# Python asyncio runs slower

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am new to Python and parallel execution and asyncio. Am I doing this incorrectly? My code runs slower (or at best equal) to the time it takes the scrip to run in a traditional manner, without asyncio.

```
import asyncio, os, time, pandas as pd
start_time = time.time()

async def main():
    coroutines = list()
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.', topdown=True):
        for file in files:
            coroutines.append(cleaner(file))
        await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)

async def cleaner(file):
 df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\n', header=None, engine='python', quoting=3)
 df = df[0].str.strip(' \t"').str.split('[,|;: \t]+', 1, expand=True).rename(columns={0: 'email', 1: 'data'}) 
 df[['email', 'data']].to_csv('x1', sep=':', index=False, header=False, mode='a', compression='gzip')


asyncio.run(main())
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Does `cleaner` read/write the file system synchronously? Running parallel cleaner instead of asyncio may indeed be faster if processing in one thread overlaps waiting on I/O in another thread. Its faster still if you are doing pandas operations that release the GIL and allow true parallelism.

Comment: asyncio may be no faster than a multithreaded app once either one of them has enough work to consume an entire cpu. asyncio has the advantage that it doesn't have to lock shared data and all of the problems that go with it.

Comment: Indeed... cleaner does write to multiple files. Hence, the output destination is shared between various coroutines. What do u suggest tdelaney?

Comment: Assuming the processing of each file is independent of the others, this is a great candidate for `multiprocessing.Pool`, or even for pulling `cleaner` into a separate python file and running it with `subprocess`. I'll post an example.

Comment: And BTW, `coroutines.append(cleaner(file))` calls `cleaner` and puts its result in the coroutines list. It should result in an error when you try to run it.

Comment: tdelaney: I have updated my ques. I dont get any errors. the script runs perfectly

Comment: There is no `await` inside `cleaner`, hence no “breakpoint” which would yield to any other async tasks, hence the async processing can only add overhead with no benefits. Asyncio isn’t multithreading, it’s cooperative multitasking within one thread.

Comment: deceze: pls help update the code

Comment: Your code cannot be updated because the concept is flawed.  Asyncio has performance benefits ONLY when you have multiple tasks that "wait" for some event or resource, and while one task waits another can proceed.  Your code must have awaitable objects that take advantage of this. Declaring a function "await def" does not confer any benefit unless it contains an "await" statement, and the await statement really has something that it has to wait for.

Comment: Pauk: Makes sense.. what is the correct way to code? I am still learning Python, and hence any help is appreciated. if you could help give me some structure around how the code should be setup - i can take it from there

Answer (score 1):

Your workload appears to be read file --> process with pandas --> write file. This is an ideal candidate for multiprocessing because each work item is very much independent. `pandas` routines that read/write the file system, like any blocking operation, are not good candidates for asyncio unless you run them in asyncio's thread or process pools.

Conversely, these multiple operations are good candidates for true parallel execution which asyncio doesn't give you. (its thread and process pools are good choices too).

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os

def walk_all_files(path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.', topdown=True):
        for file in files:
            yield os.path.join(root, file)

def cleaner(path):
    return "sparkly"

def clean_all(path="."):
    files = list(walk_all_files(path))
    # using cpu*2 assuming that there is a lot of cpu heavy
    # work that can be done by some processes while others
    # wait on I/O. This is only a guess.
    cpu_count = min(len(files), mp.cpu_count()*2)
    with mp.Pool(cpu_count) as pool:
        # assuming processing is fairly long but also kindof random depending on
        # file contents, setting chunksize to 1 so that subprocess gets new work
        # item from parent on each round. You could set it higher to have fewer
        # interactions between parent and worker.
        result = pool.map(cleaner, files, chunksize=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    clean_all(".")
```

Comment: thanks tdelaney: apologies, I am too new to this. I am not able to follow your code. i have updated my ques, to give a demo of the cleaner function

Comment: I get a error: AttributeError: module 'multiprocessing' has no attribute 'map'

Comment: sorry about that. should have been `pool.map`